# Import cv2 missing - python3.7

Tags: python, opencv, import

I am trying to import cv2 from the python modules in site packages.

I've seen other solutions where you add the module into the site packages directory for python, did pip install and was notified that it installed correctly. I also did a reinstall of the module and its opencv-contrib-python.

When installing opencv-python and attempting to import cv2, I also recieved an error message that there was recursions in the ini file for open cv.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using python3, you'll need to do

```
pip3 install opencv-contrib-python
```

Comment: This worked on windows 11 python 3.9.3. Simple opencv-python did not work.

Answer (score 0):

How do you install opencv? do you try this code?

```
pip install opencv-python
```

try it and open a new python file and type this code on it.

```
import cv2
print(cv2.__version__)
```

check this answer and report result. good luck!

Answer (score 0):

hi sir try doing this:

> pip install opencv-python

instead of this:

> pip install opencv-contrib-python

hope this helps :)) i also had a problem installing it but fixed it easily. if you have any problems, feel free to ask more

Comment: I tried both of these methods and it was stil having the same issue, but I opened a python project in Visual Studio Community and found a python environment window that does the install automatically and it worked. Not sure why. the pip installs and anaconda both said they were installed correctly.

Comment: @TaurianGraham I am having the same issue with both methods too. Can you share the details of the python environment that you used and that worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

I used unstructured with detectron2 on, but it doesn't work, then I found out that it's missing cv2, this works for me:

```
opencv-python-headless==4.5.4.60
```